# Quitar sombras en el margen del código

Tags: visual-studio, color, style, margin, shadow

Hola a todos y antes de nada, gracias por leerme
El caso es que en visual studio code me sale una sombra en el código y no se como quitarla, en la foto que mando es la de color verde oscuro, es la franja vertical, he estado buscando pero no lo encuentro, gracias y un saludo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tema estás usando? Alguna extensión que maneje los espacios en blanco?

Answer (score 0):

### Edición

Extensiones como [indent-rainbow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow) son las que colorean las indentaciones como lo que muestras en la figura.
Es muy probable que la tengas instalada u otra similar.
Deberías desinstalarla o desactivarla accediendo al panel izquierdo de Extensiones `Ctrl+Shift+X`

---

### Respuesta inicial dejada por si sea de utilidad para otros casos

Al parecer es la manera en que el editor te muestra los espacios en blanco.

En la configuración hay una propiedad `Render Whitespace` que controla esto. La opción por defecto es *`selection`* pero en tu caso parece que tiene el valor *`boundary`*.

Prueba cambiando estos valores a ver si encuentras el que te satisfaga.

Comment: Hola, he entrado en la propiedad Render Whitespace y efectivamente la opción por defecto es selection como dices y es donde la tenía, he probado todas las opciones y en todas me sale la sobra lo único que cambia son unos puntos que salen, que en una opción salen en la misma sobra y en otra opción al final, lo extraño es que he estado trabajando sin esa sombra sin problema y ahora me sale, tampoco es un gran problema pero me gustaba mas de la otra manera, seguiré buscando, gracias por la ayuda y un saludo

Comment: Ya te lo había preguntado pero te lo vuelvo a recalcar. Por si acaso no tienes instaladas extensiones que manejen esas cosas? Especificamente la extensión [indent-rainbow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow) veo ahora que hace eso.

Answer (score 0):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "transparent"

 }
```

En configuración buscando "workbench.colorCustomizations"
Espero que no solo a ti sea de ayuda.